# What are the coefficients of the hyperplane given above

Tags: vector-analysis

I am not sure how to find the coefficients of hyperplane. Could you please help me to understand the concept.

Consider a data set with two independent variables, say X1 and X2, and one dependent binary variable, Y, with two class labels denoted by +1 and -1. The data set is plotted along with a separating hyperplane (h) in the figure below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JHv9.jpg)

the following two constraints determine the equation of the maximal margin classifier:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNMW5.jpg)

With the above information, answer the questions below.

What are the coefficients of the hyperplane given above?
A. W0 =0, W1=1, W2=0
B. W0 =1, W1=1, W2=1
C. W0 =0,  W1 = 1/Sqrt2,  W2= -1/Sqrt2
D. W0 =1, W1=0, W2=0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the given hyperplane X1 = X2 with the general equation of 2D hyperplane i.e W0+W1∗X1+W2∗X2=0, you will notice that the given hyper plane can also be written as X1-X2 = 0. Now if you compare it with the general form of equation, you will get W0=0, W1 = 1 and W2 = -1. Imposing the condition that the weights should form a unit vector, i.e. the squares of W1 and W2 should add to 1, W1 = 1/sqrt(2) and W2 = -1/sqrt(2).